# How do I disable the XMRig donate function?

Tags: xmrig

I am using XMRig on Windows 10 to mine Monero and I want to know how to disable donations. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about XMRig but for XMR-Stak one had to compile from source with the tweaks.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think Windows 10 is different, in that you can edit the source code, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You would need to checkout the git, make the source code tweaks, and also make sure you have the tool chain to compile it.  The github page should provide 'how to compile' instructions with all requirements needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should still donate to the devs of xmrig but if you don't wanna you can download the xmrig repository at [their github](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig)

and edit the file "donate.h" in the directory "src".

Change both:
constexpr const int kDefaultDonateLevel = 1;
constexpr const int kMinimumDonateLevel = 1;
to 0.

Next: Compile it for your system.

You can find the compilation guide for windows at their [website](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/build/windows)

and as Jerzy Brzóska said, you will need to make sure donate-level is set to 0 in the config.json file as well.

Comment: Thanks! That's great. I still want to donate, but I just wanted to decrease the amount.

Comment: @g3holliday You can still send some of your moneroj to the xmrig devs since it has it on their website.

Comment: OK. I'll try to do that. I really appreciate the help. Thanks :)

Comment: One also needs to make sure that they have the following set in their config.json: `"donate-level": 0`. From the names of the constants in `donate.h` it can be inferred that they are responsible for the default and for the minimum donation. If the default level can be overridden by `donate-level` in `config.json` then, as in the case of @g3holliday, one needs to set it to **0**.

Comment: Instead of building from scratch, you can download the pre-build Linux binary: https://github.com/danger89/xmrig/releases

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build from scratch and you're using Linux (sorry that you use Windows). Just use [my fork](https://github.com/danger89/xmrig) and download the latest release from: https://github.com/danger89/xmrig/releases